# How to perform an MD5 verification on source and destination after copying

Tags: powershell, hash, md5, robocopy

We have a ~4gb of payload that we need to robocopy over to multiple geographies and some times the assemblies(dll files) get corrupted over the wire. I am using get-hash function in powershell and my example code snippet looks like this

```
# PowerShell Invoke-Command source Machine has check
Clear-Host
Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock {dir C:\swtools\7-Zip -Recurse | Where-Object {!$_.psiscontainer } | get-hash | Out-File c:\temp\source.md5.txt}

# PowerShell Invoke-Command on Remote Computer to check filehash at Dest
Clear-Host
Invoke-Command -Computer Remote_Host -ScriptBlock {dir e:\downloads\7-zip -Recurse | Where-Object {!$_.psiscontainer } | get-hash } | Out-File c:\temp\dest.md5.txt

# PowerShell compare to check if the md5 hashes are equal at source and dest

Compare-Object $(Get-Content c:\temp\source.md5.txt) $(Get-Content c:\temp\dest.md5.txt) -includeequal
```

This does not solve the problem because the output of the get-hash contains filepath added to the file name, so I cannot really do a 1:1 comparison with filename and hash at source and file name and hash from destination because the output contains full file path which differs

So what is the best way to ensure that md5 checksum of all assemblies copied from source to destination are matching ?

Note: I am not looking at creating additional files where I push only the file name and hash via a regular expression etc, the time and memory would be an issue.

Comment: Why can't you have a script run though the file first and modify the filenames? Surely you have an algorithm to convert source to destination paths?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could pipe to `Tee-Object` in order to dump to file (if you feel the need to dump to file), and then to `Select-Object` to modify the `Path` value to exclude the root path, and capture that in a variable to run your `Compare-Object` against. The following would output your files, and capture a modified version of the Hash output where the Path would exclude the root path, and only include subfolder and file names.

```
# PowerShell Invoke-Command source Machine has check
Clear-Host
$LocalRoot = [RegEx]::Escape('C:\swtools\7-Zip')
$LocalHash = Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock {dir C:\swtools\7-Zip -Recurse | Where-Object {!$_.psiscontainer } | get-hash} | Tee-Object -File c:\temp\source.md5.txt | Select *,@{l='Path';e={$_.Path -replace $LocalRoot}} -ExcludeProperty Path

# PowerShell Invoke-Command on Remote Computer to check filehash at Dest
Clear-Host
$DestRoot = [RegEx]::Escape('e:\downloads\7-zip')
$DestHash = Invoke-Command -Computer Remote_Host -ScriptBlock {dir e:\downloads\7-zip -Recurse | Where-Object {!$_.psiscontainer } | get-hash } | Tee-Object -file c:\temp\dest.md5.txt | Select *,@{l='Path';e={$_.Path -replace $DestRoot}} -ExcludeProperty Path

# PowerShell compare to check if the md5 hashes are equal at source and dest

Compare-Object $LocalHash $DestHash -includeequal
```

Comment: Its working on a list of 500 files, will need to run it on a 20000 files and see how it goes  , thanks !